# Grails best practice on form redirection/rendering

Tags: grails, command-objects

If I have an action `def formPage()`, I want to be able to save the form on that page, show the form with the previously entered values if there's an error, and show a blank form if it's a success.

My question is: Is it best practice for `formPage` to call something like `saveFormPage(FormPageCommand fpc)`? `saveFormPage` can then render `formPage` with or without the previously entered values. The problem with this approach is that the user can click the address bar, press enter, and then get a slew of errors since the form hasn't been filled in, and the command object sees all the null or blank values.

Another approach might be to just have a `def formPage(FormPageCommand fpc)`, and ignore errors and just show a blank form if none of the values are filled in.

One might also call `saveFormPage(FormPageCommand fpc)` and redirect back to `formPage()` if none of the values are filled in.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

Your controller

```
class MyFormController {
    def formPage() {
        [cmd: new FormPageCommand()]
    }

    def saveFormPage(FormPageCommand cmd) {
        if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
            render view: "formPage", model: [cmd: cmd]
        } else {
            // Process form
            // ......

            // Redirect back formPage() to display a new form
            redirect action: "formPage"
        }
    }
}
```

Your command object

```
class FormPageCommand {
    String optionalValue
    String requiredValue

    static constraints = {
        optionalValue(nullable: true, blank: true)
        requiredValue(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
}
```

Your formPage.gsp

```
<g:form controller="myForm" action="saveFormPage" method="POST">

  <label>Required value *</label>
  <g:textField name="requiredValue" value="${cmd.requiredValue}"/>
  <g:if test="${cmd.errors.getFieldError('requiredValue')}">
    <g:message error="${cmd.errors.getFieldError('requiredValue')}"/>
  </g:if>

  <label>Optional value</label>
  <g:textField name="optionalValue" value="${cmd.optionalValue}"/>

  <g:submitButton name="submit"/>

</g:form>
```

It should serve your need.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but to get you started I recommend the book "Grails in Action". It contains a lot of best practices and chapter 7 on data binding and error handling may give you some good advice and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem before and solved it this way:

My registration form has a button:

```
<g:submitButton name="register" value="Register" />
```

So the incoming params map should have the "register" key with "Register" value.

Then I check the existence of this parameter in my controller:

```
def register(UserRegisterCommand urc) {
    if (params.register) {
        //some registration actions
    } 
}
```

In other words I check in the controller if the "Register" button was clicked, if yes - then perform registration actions. If no - the "register.gsp" is rendered.

I hope this will help.